# Max-Width on DIV with Display: Table

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a div which have `display:table; max-width: 800px`. It should act as a frame to restrict the contents width. Inside the frame are images which auto-scale and are nested inside div's with `display:table-cell`.

Everything is working on Chrome and Mobile Safari, but Firefox and IE are not restricting the frame width.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLF9c/42/)

Can anybody help me, please ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLF9c/44/)

Replace max-width to width from image css, the reason behind this is max-width does not apply to inline elements, so you will get inconsistent behavior across browsers.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: it work's but can you explain me, why it is? where is the difference, if the img has `width:100%` and `max-width:100%`? because if i use that globally all my other images are scaled up more than their actual size.

Answer (score 9):

Set the table to have `table-layout: fixed` and a width of 100%.

```css
.frame {
  display: table;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same here, just the images are resizing, but this time in chrome too